# How to change only xticks fontsize in pandas Dataframe barplot?

Tags: python, pandas, bar-chart

I want to create a barplot from pandas. But I want to change fontsize for x and y-axis separately.

This code:

> ```
> max_coef.plot.bar(fontsize = 15, x = 'coef_word', y = 'coefficient', color=['yellow'])
> ```

Creates this plot:

[image]

I tried to play around with xticks and xticklabels, but apparently this does not work similar to matplotlib syntax. I already checked documentation but I cannot wrap my head around it.

I want to change x and y ticks separately. Please help. +
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, you can do something like this.

```
data.plot.bar(fontsize = 15, x = 'coef_word', y = 'coefficient', color=['yellow'])
plt.xticks(fontsize=7)  # for xticks
plt.yticks(fontsize=24) # for yticks
```

Sorry for weird values, just to show the change

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Always good to know more than one step!

Comment: Just a reminder, this will set the values for the current plot only

Answer (score 2):

See the code below for changing the font size:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

SMALL_SIZE = 8
MEDIUM_SIZE = 10
BIG_SIZE = 12

plt.rc('font', size=SMALL_SIZE)          # default text sizes
plt.rc('axes', titlesize=MEDIUM_SIZE )   # axes title fontsize
plt.rc('axes', labelsize=MEDIUM_SIZE)    # x and y labels fontsize
plt.rc('xtick', labelsize=MEDIUM_SIZE )  # x tick labels fontsize
plt.rc('ytick', labelsize=MEDIUM_SIZE )  # y tick labels fontsize
plt.rc('legend', fontsize=MEDIUM_SIZE )  # legend fontsize
plt.rc('figure', titlesize=BIGGER_SIZE)  # figure title fontsize
```

You may find more info here: [matplotlib rc](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.rc.html)

Comment: thanks for that detailed answers. you may want to share the documentation link?

Comment: Added documentation link